# export the aov() output via gtsummary()

Tags: r, anova, gtsummary

I try to get a nice output from an aov() function, the publication-ready type, via the package gtsummary but I get an error message that I do not know how to solve because I do not understand the origin of it.

Please, could someone help me with:

- understanding the error message?
- getting the nice output?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

aov(data = chickwts,
    formula = weight ~ feed) %>% 
  summary()
```

The output is as such:
[image]

I would like to get this output but with the nice gtsummary formatting. So, I add the command that I thought would be appropriate:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

aov(data = chickwts,
    formula = weight ~ feed) %>% 
    tbl_summary()
```

and I got the following error message:

Error in UseMethod("ungroup") :
no applicable method for 'ungroup' applied to an object of class "c('aov', 'lm')"

Please, could someone help me with:

- understanding the error message?
- getting the nice output (if it is possible)?

I read that [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68722812/is-it-possible-to-extract-the-full-output-for-the-statistical-tests-performed-in), the request was completed but it does not help me with this problem

Comment: The `tbl_summary()` function is for summarizing data frames. You can include p-values from the `aov()` test with `add_p()`. But you cannot directly summarize the results of the object.

Comment: ah ok, I did not understand that the `aov()` output was not readable at all by `tbl_summary()`, thank you for your help.